# VS 2013 - What Is Creating .TMP Files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013. Every time I click save, no matter what class, view, whatever, VS creates a .TMP file. Looks like some kind of backup.

I've got DOZENS of .TMP files in every folder in my solution.

I've looked all over the settings and I don't see an option to disabvle this? Anyone know how to stop this?

This doesn't happen on my Home Dev PC, only here at the office.

Thanks

Comment: go through this: [.TMP Files](http://forums.asp.net/t/1138275.aspx?What+is+TMP+files+and+how+to+solve+them+without+re+appearing)...the solution may be conclusive...anyway, see the last 2 replies...I guess that might work..

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
Tools >> Import and Export Settings >> Reset all Settings
```

PS: I browsed internet and tried many things but nothing worked. Ultimately Resetting the Settings works in such cases.